# Excel formula: search in column by another value (LIKE)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having a problem in Excel, where I'm trying to search an entire column for a name (not necessarily 100% identical) that is in another column.

The following table for a better explanation:

```
---------------------------------------
NAME          CITY       FATHER NAME     
---------------------------------------
Saad Test     New York   William Jack
Jack Jacking  Paris      Noah Saad   
Adam King     Rabat      William Sara
Sara Best     Madrid     Benjamin Adam
```

Briefly: I want to get the father's name by using only the name column. Is there a way to do that? (The order of the fathers’ names is incorrect, so I want to search using the name, if it is present in the father’s name, then it is the result I want)

Example: `Saad test` his father's name is `Noah Saad` (Match by `Saad`)

PS: I tried using `LOOKUP`, `VLOOKUP` and `MATCH`, but unfortunately the result is always N/A

PS 2: The data I have in Arabic is the reason why the above functions are not working?

Comment: Have you tried MATCH combined with wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

I would use index() with match(), assuming your data starts in cell A1, like so:

```
=index(C1:C4,match(F1,A1:A4,0))
```

F1 contains the name that you look for.

Note, the classic problem is that there are extra spaces (leading or trailing) that make the names not identical.

You can trap errors as so:

```
=iferror(index(C1:C4,match(F1,A1:A4,0)),"Check")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir, but I want to get the father's name by using only the name column, Meaning, I want to search by "Saad" only, and get the name of the father, for example (You can change the order of parents' names, to understand my problem exactly)

Comment: That is exactly what I showed you how to do. matching the contents of F1 (Saad or Jack) in cells A1: A4, then index() returns the father's name based on the position value returned by the match. Obviously you did not try it or you have an error, perhaps of the type I suggested.

Comment: I used the same code and the result was "William Jack" instead of "Noah Saad" (I changed the order of the table in the question, to better understand the problem)

Comment: A1:A4 must change with C1:C4, I think

Comment: Are you now saying that that table is not a table of data? That any one row is not coherent information? If that is the case then you will need to expand on the method I showed you.

Comment: Yes, the problem is more than that, the name I have does not contain one word, but two or more words, which means that matching them is difficult (I have to find a way to divide the name)

Comment: Then you can use wildcards or left(0 and right() with find() to separate the first name  from the family name.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
=INDEX( $C$2:$C$5, MATCH( "*" & MID( A2, 1, FIND( " ", A2 )-1), $C$2:$C$5,0) )
```

> SolarMike - I think you have said the same, so I'm sorry if I am
> stepping on your answer.

[image]

Comment: Just reading this comment "...the problem is more than that, the name I have does not contain one word, but two or more words...". Unless the first word in Name is the element to be matched, my answer will not work for you.